# New Zend framework changes in Zend/Db/Sql/columns causes problems

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, apostrophe

Our framework sits on top of the Zend framework. A change in the way columns() is working causes problems with our database calls. Before, it was fine to do something like:

```
$distanceFormula = "$earthRadius*ACOS(COS(RADIANS($lat)))";
$select->columns(array('distance' => $distanceFormula));
```

This created a query:

```
SELECT `items`.*, 6371*ACOS(COS(RADIANS(51.985103)) AS `distance`
```

NOW it creates a query:

```
SELECT `items`.*, `6371*ACOS(COS(RADIANS(51.985103))` AS `distance`
```

columns() puts ` (apostrophe) around everything so we get the following error:

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception
Mysqli prepare error: Unknown column '6371*ACOS.... etc
```

Is there a way to tell columns not to put the formula between apostrophes?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if the formula is entered as Zend_Db_Expr, everything works fine.

```
$distanceFormula = new Zend_Db_Expr("($earthRadius*ACOS(COS(RADIANS($lat))");
$select->columns(array('distance' => $distanceFormula));
```